# Spacy download en not working in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, virtualenv, spacy

I'm new to python and virtualenv. I have pip installed and have installed a virtualenv, through which I have downloaded the python NLP library spacy. Now I am having an issue downloading a language library (en). The command I run is:

```
$ python3 -m spacy download en
```

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .link import link
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..util import prints
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/regex.py", line 683, in <module>
    _pattern_type = type(_compile("", 0, {}))
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/regex.py", line 436, in _compile
    pattern_locale = _getlocale()[1]
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 581, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/JoshiMac/Documents/pythonprojects/LangEnv/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 490, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: try executing 'export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' and  'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' before the download command

Comment: Try this `echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bash_profile && echo 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`, then retry the spacy download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1684 . 
Add the following in your bash

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: These aliases worked for me. Others suggested without "export" before, but that didn't work. Then I tried these and they worked like a charm :)
Thanks!!